# How to send keystrokes to a textbox that remains hidden until it's clicked on?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to log into [this site](https://www.icaionlineregistration.org/admin_module/login.aspx). But I can't even fill the textbox with the username.

I tried:

- implicit and explicit waits
- executing JavaScript

**Structure of the textbox**

The username is enclosed within a `td` tag, which can be located using its width attribute. The textbox itself is represented by two `input` tags. The first one is hidden. Both have `style` attributes. The first one has an initial value of `display: none;`, which is changed to `display: inline-block;` when I click on the textbox. And the `style` attribute of the second input tag is set to `display: none;`. Again, both these are toggled once the username textbox loses focus.

**Waits**

I tried using both implicit and explicit waits. The code implementing explicit wait resulted in a `TimeoutException` error:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem_username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'txt_username')))
```

**Executing JavaScript**

Both the `input` tags have `onfocus` and `onchange` attributes. I didn't bother about the latter (my goal was to get keystrokes into the textbox first). The `onfocus` has a value of `SetEnd(this)`. So, I tried to execute that.

The problem I had is that I couldn't find any documentation that could help me executing JavaScript. So I looked at a few related answers here at StackOverflow. I tried this first:

```
elem_username = driver.find_element_by_id('txt_username')
driver.execute_script('SetEnd(this)')
```

Of course, I knew it wouldn't work, because I was not referring to the element. So after browsing a few more questions, I learnt that execute_script took arguments. So I modified the code, which raised an error that said something like the script had no function like this:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].SetEnd(this)', elem_username)
```

Then, I saw an answer using 'click()' inside the `execute_script`; so I tried that, too:

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', elem_username)
```

The 'click()', I guess, is only for buttons. But since I had to "click" in the textbox to bring it in focus, I thought it would work. It didn't.

This is the last line I executed in all of my attempts, which, without an exception, kept raising `ElementNotInteractableException` error:

```
elem_username.send_keys('blahblahblah')
```

**Requirements**

The Q&As on this site would, of course, be excellent, if I had a bit more experience. For instance, there are several answers demonstrating explicit wait, but most of them were aimed at solving the OP's problem, and hence they included only the relevant parts of code. It was tough for me to understand them.

I want to solve this problem (logging into the site), but I also want to *learn working with selenium properly*. I haven't worked with it earlier in any other languages such as Java. The official documentation is good, but I couldn't solve this problem using that. So I want a more beginner-friendly tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
# Force the element to be displayed (noticed style.display = "none")
# Yes, I know you can see it, but selenium thinks it's not displayed.
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("txt_username")[0].style.display="block"')

elem_username.send_keys('your name')
```

Comment: It worked for me, too. Do you have any idea why two text boxes appear? https://imgur.com/a/yWcYb

Comment: I'm not sure what styling they're using behind the scenes, and what all of their interactive javascript code does to the element. It does appear odd that a mirror of the object is displayed. The page source doesn't show a duplicate entry.

Comment: Your solution solved this problem. But, as I said the question, I want to learn this in a proper way. Could you tell me how I should go about it?

Answer (score 0):

So you've outlined everything well and you seem to have a good understanding of it. The trick is to click the second `input` first, then send keys to the first `input` since it is then focused. (I did find that clicking the containing `td` also worked for Chrome, but browsers are different in that aspect and the intent of this page is that you click on the second input). A simple solution is as follows:

```
real, readonly = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[onfocus*='SetEnd']")
readonly.click()
real.send_keys('hi')
```

If you have any questions about that, I can try to help.

Comment: That worked. I'm still looking for a way to learn working with selenium properly, which is why I haven't accepted either of your answers. I've upvoted them, but they solve my temporary problem alone.

Comment: I ended up accepting Ron's answer (as his was first), because I saw a couple of posts on the meta site and found that I wasn't supposed to ask for "tutorials". So, since this particular problem got solved, this question didn't have much purpose to stay open.